# ¿Como crear múltiples sesiones en un WebView?

Tags: java, web, javafx

**Hola**

Tengo el problema que necesito abrir 3 ventanas independientes una de la otra en una misma aplicación que cargan una misma pagina web pero las cuales deben ser independientes una de la otra. Pero al momento de ejecutar me lanza 3 ventanas pero al percatarme ambas comparten la misma **sesión de cookies**.

Este es el código que uso para configurar el WebEngine y su forma de trabajar el WebView, ademas incluso defino un directorio de datos para cada WebView instanciado.

```
public void loadURL(final String url, String userAgent,
        boolean borrarCACHE, String ruta_COOKIE){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String tmp =toURL(url);
            if(tmp == null){
                tmp = toURL(url);
            }

            engine.setUserAgent(userAgent);
            try {

                File files = new File(
                        new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "/" + ruta_COOKIE);

                if(!files.exists()){
                   files.mkdir();

                }

                engine.setUserDataDirectory(files);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(browser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener(new WebConsoleListener() {

                @Override
                public void messageAdded(WebView webView, String message, int lineNumber, String sourceId) {
                    System.out.println("Console [" + sourceId + " - " + lineNumber + " ] "
                    + message);
                }

            });



            engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                //engine.userDataDirectoryProperty();


            CookieHandler.setDefault(new com.sun.webkit.network.CookieManager());

            if(!borrarCACHE){

                CookieManager cookieM = new CookieManager();


                CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieM);
                cookieM.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
                cookieM.getCookieStore().removeAll();

                engine.load("about:blank");

            }   

            engine.setUserStyleSheetLocation("");
            engine.load(tmp);

        }
    });

}
```

Ya no encuentro que hacer, estoy utilizando el JDK 8 y no hay nada de documentación que explique claramente como separar las sesiones. **Gracias** y espero su apoyo.

Comment: Quieres mostrar 3 Webviews al mismo tiempo pero que estos creen su propia cookie?

Comment: Si amigo, que cada webView sea independiente y no intervenga con las cookies del otro.

Comment: Todas las instancias de WebView hacen uso de `java.net.CookieHandler`(o de su clase hija CookieManager, ya que CookieHandler es una clase abstracta). Para obtener el manejador de cookies, simplemente llaman a `CookieHandler.getDefault()`.
Esto es útil porque tienes en un único sitio sincronizadas las cookies de todos tus webviews. El problema es que justamente es lo que no quieres hacer.

Comment: Si amigo ese es mi problema principal.

Comment: probaste hacer una tabbed page y en cada tab un webview?

Comment: si amigo ocurre lo mismo.